# Using local::lib with 3-rd party shared .so libraries

Tags: perl, shared-libraries, cpan, language-binding, locallib

I have a Perl library that consists of a C library in a binary form (`.so` file) and sources for Perl bindings for that library (`Makefile.PL` etc).

All I need is an ability to run Perl samples shipped with the library. I'd like to avoid installing anything globally or changing system-wide configs.

So I created a special user and I want everything to run inside the home dir. Changing environment and adding files/folders in the homedir is fine of course.

I already have `local::lib` and various CPAN helpers installed system-wide (`cpan`, `cpanp` and `cpanm` so I can use them if they are of any help.

I could create `~/lib` and put `.so` there, or put it somewhere inside `~/perl5`.

The question is how to make the shared C library available to the Perl bindings during compilation and during runtime. It seems I need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LDFLAGS` environment variables but I'm not sure how to use them together with `local::lib`.

Moreover the library comes named as `foo.1.2.3.4.so` but linker wants `-lfoo`. Am I supposed to create `foo.so -> foo.1.2.3.4.so` symlink myself?

Upd:

The relevant part of generated `Makefile`:

```
    LD_RUN_PATH="$(LD_RUN_PATH)" $(LD)  $(LDDLFLAGS) $(LDFROM) $(OTHERLDFLAGS) -o $@ $(MYEXTLIB)    \
      $(PERL_ARCHIVE) $(LDLOADLIBS) $(PERL_ARCHIVE_AFTER) $(EXPORT_LIST)    \
      $(INST_DYNAMIC_FIX)
```

Patching LDDLFLAGS to include an extra `-L` switch works but feels dirty.